# Как правильно сохранить дататест с помощью pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Есть текстовый файл, его нужно обработать и записать данные в csv файл.
Я обрабатываю данные и по строчке присоединяю их к заранее созданному датасету, а потом сохраняю этот датасет. Но данные сохраняются в один столбик. Что я делаю не так?

```
import pandas as pd

#создаем датафрейм
col_names = ['%h', '%l', '%u', '%t', '%r', '%>s', '%b', '%{Referr}i', '%{Useragent}i']
my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)

newline = {'%h' : resultList[0], '%l' : resultList[1], '%u' : resultList[2], '%t': resultList[3], '%r' : resultList[4], '%>s' : resultList[5], '%b' : resultList[6], '%{Referr}i' : resultList[7], '%{Useragent}i' : resultList[8]}
my_df = my_df.append(newline, ignore_index = True)
print(my_df.head())

my_df.to_csv('file1.csv', header=True)
```

Это пример кода, который я использую для создания и для записи.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно только гадать, поскольку вы не привели примеры данных и не написали, в чём вы смотрите выходной файл, но полагаю, что вы пытаетесь открывать полученный `csv` файл в `Excel`, а он хочет другой разделитель столбцов, чем тот, который делает `Pandas` по умолчанию. Попробуйте поставить разделитель `;`, который будет понятен `Excel`:

```
my_df.to_csv('file1.csv', header=True, sep=';')
```